# how can I check if there is atleast one surrounding space in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a message like this:

```
Upgrade is the first word in this paragraph.
In this paragraph, upgrade is the last word.
And this paragraph ends with upgrade.
But I don't want to find that word in this command `gigalixir:upgrade`.
```

As, you can see there are 4 instances of upgrade word in this example. But I want only 3 instances. Actually I only need to split my string if the word upgrade has a space on both sides or if it starts with a space or if it ends with a space. I don't want to split if the word does not have any surrounding spaces.

So, as per the above description, only upgrade words in first 3 lines should be considered as breaking point.

## What I have tried:

```
console.log(message.split(/\s?upgrade\s?/g));
```

Can some regex expert tell me how can I check if there is atleast one surrounding space in the above regex?

Comment: You should check out look ahead and look behind regex syntax: https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/the-complicated-syntax-of-lookaheads-in-javascript-regular-expressions/

Comment: `\b` perhaps...? https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZJTJ.png

Comment: @ControlAltDel I have tried with negative lookahead like this: `/(?!:)upgrade/g`, but it is not working.

Comment: @JGFMK I am not familiar with `/b`, but will check that. Thanks.

Comment: neither `"Upgrade "` nor `" upgrade."` has whitespace on both sides. The only occurance of `upgrade` with space on both sides (as per your description) is the one in the second line.

Comment: @Thomas But it has atleast one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/PROpvQ/1

```
(?<=\s|^)[uU]pgrade\b
```

Positive look behind for space or start of string .. upgrade in upper or lowercase with a word boundary at the end. (catches space, full stop end of text etc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is more easier to understand the answer from JAT86.

Comment: Oh! I see. After checking your answer, I can see that only the upgrade word is selected. While the other answer from JAT86, was selecting spaces as well. Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: Because browsers other than Chrome, does not support lookahead or lookbehind, this pattern only works on chrome. Is there any way to ignore using lookahead or lookbehind?

Comment: I am thrown by that last comment. Are you finding that regex engines built in to browser implementations behave differently with their individual JavaScript Engines?

Comment: Yes, exactly I can reproduce that.

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

`(?:^| )[Uu]pgrade(?: ?)`

`(?:^| )` looks for either the start (`^`) of the line or (`|`) a leading space  . The surrounding parentheses `()` are used for grouping so that we can properly use the "or" sign `|`. `?:` is optional and only is used to ignore capturing the matches within the enclosing parentheses. `[Uu]` matches either a single lowercase or uppercase "u".

`(?: ?)` looks for a trailing space.  `?` means to match zero or one single space.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works perfectly but I did not understand anything there. :)
Can you please try to explain me in more detail?

Comment: Won't work for first unless you have a case insensitive search `/gi` flag according to Regex101

Comment: Your answer selects spaces around upgrade word. Is there any way to remove those spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language it could be different:

```
console.log(message.split(/(\s*)upgrade(\s*)/g));
if (length($1) > 0 and length($2) > 0) { GOOD }
else { BAD } # No space chars on either side of 'upgrade'
```

\s matches spaces and tabs, so use (\ *) if you only care about spaces and not tabs

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but answer from @JAT86 is more accurate to my problem.